# Questions Regarding Blue Card Application Procedure Germany - Can I Start Working Right After Blue Card Application?

Tags: germany, blue-card

My situation is as follows:

- I will submit my MSc. Thesis on December 2022 and present it on January 2023. As a result, I can receive my degree on January 2023 earliest.
- I have a job offer to start as of 20.02.2023 from a remote company **which has a German legal entity** and they will hire me under their Germany entity. **However**, they require me to present a valid work permit before I start my work.

**Question 1)**: If I wait until I receive my degree to apply for Blue Card, some time in January, would it be too late to receive the confirmation? What is the procedure after Blue Card application? Can I start working right after my application?

**Question 2)**: Is there a criteria such that the job has to be advertised for 10 days and should be proved that position can not be filled by a EU national?

**Question 3)**: Does immigration office accept digitally signed job contract or does it have to be signed by ink?

Thank you for everyone's kind help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that it usually works is that you sign a contract with whatever company you are going to work for and show it to the Ausländeramt to get the work permit. So, you need to show them proof that you already have work before they give you the permit.

For any application, blue card or not, the standard way is that you have the signed contract in your hands and show it to whoever wants to see it. I would clarify with the company: why do they ask a valid 'work' permit before you start? Ask them, how is that possible? You can show them your valid current permit instead, that should be enough for them to give you a contract.

After your Masters, your measure of last resort is to get a 6 months job-seeker permit (while in Germany) but you have to show a blocked account with some money in it. During these 6 months hopefully you will have a contract.

The criterion is not your concern, if you have the contract, you have the contract.

Ask your office if they accept digitally signed ones, they might make an exception if they are nice, but I suspect you should not expect it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I start working right after I submit my BlueCard application how long does it take for me to start working after submitting BlueCard application?

Comment: Thanks for upvoting and accepting the answer ;). The date you start working is written on the contract. You can have a contract starting the next day after your Masters completion, for example.